# Error gem install pg with on Mac Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql

I was trying to use `postgresql` with `Ruby on Rails`

However, I type `gem install pg`, it comes with an error

```
Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/Coda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/pg-0.18.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/pg-0.18.2/gem_make.out
```

Environment: Mac OSX 10.10

rails version: Rails 4.1.8

ruby version: ruby 2.1.3

Comment: Do you have PG installed? you will need the libraries to compile the gem's C extensions.

Comment: I think I haven't done that before.

Comment: Well... Now is as good a time as any :-)   -   The Database installation is a requirement. From my experience, it's almost impossible to install the Gem without the Database's libraries.

Comment: I figure it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First,I downloaded and and installed `Postgres.app` at [here](http://postgresapp.com/), then set the right `Path`

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin`

Final, retype the command

`gem install pg`